# How to create a bounding box around an object using three min js

Tags: automation, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Create a bounding box around 3d objects and rotate them according to object

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The question is a bit vague, the API can give you the information about axis-aligned bounding box for each component. Computing optimized bounding boxes is much harder to accomplish and there is no standard way to accomplish this.

You can refer to that article for a starting point on the topic:

[Getting bounding boxes of each component in the viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/getting-bounding-boxes-of-each-component-in-the-viewer.html)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply sir, i have used n implemented this api but the problem is when the objects are rotated the bounding box should also rotate,

Comment: As I mentioned the bounding box returned by the API is always axis-aligned, so rotating the object will not rotate the bounding box. You should apply the same rotation to the box than the one applied to the component, it will give you expected result. If your component are not rotated by your application, then there is no direct way to get the oriented bbox, it has to be computed by custom algorithm.